Async methods transient factory - still getting A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed
OrderItems and OrderTaxLines are ienumerables, to be displayed in grids. there is no, to my knowledge, awaitable functions to get them. I don't see what else could be the problem
protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
    if (Order != null)
    {
        OrderItems = db.OrderItems.Include(o => o.Product).Include(o => o.productSubChoice).Where(c => c.Status != Status.Deleted && c.OrderID == Order.ID);
        if (Order.OrderStatusID == InProgressStatusID)
            await Order.UpdatePriceList(db);

        await UpdateTaxesLines();
        OrderSubTotal = OrderItems.Sum(i => i.TotalPrice);
        OrderTotal = OrderSubTotal + OrderTaxLines.Sum(t => t.Value);

    }
}
public async Task UpdateTaxesLines()
{

    OrderTaxLines = db.OrderTaxLines.Include(t => t.Tax).Where(c => c.Status != Status.Deleted && c.OrderID == Order.ID);

}

enter image description here

Please see the reference to the question I believe provides information on this issue.  Also see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#use-a-dbcontext-factory
